# Set 1 minute in a timer

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

Im going to have this objects: textbox,progress bar and button.
I need to push the button and start 1 minute, then you enter integers in the texbox and they have to be count it and sum it later when the minute ends... show how many numbers i input and the sum..
so far i understand how run a timer but how i give condition for this process, i mean i capture the numbers  but how i link the time and the progress bar?

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim recolector As Integer
    Dim contador As Integer
    Dim sumatoria As Integer

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAgregar.Click
        Try
            recolector = Integer.Parse(txtNumero.Text)


        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
    End Sub


    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        Timer1.Interval = 60000

        While Timer1.Interval < 60000


        End While
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: that is an endless while loop - the interval does not change in the Tick event.  Start the Timer in the button click event, and the tick event should mark the end of the 1 min challenge/game whatever.

Comment: You apparently don't know how to run a timer. I'd start by doing research to figure that out first.

Comment: sorry i dont understand what you mean? Can you explain me..  im learning visual so :-(

Comment: Sorry, SO is not a tutorial service.  You are supposed to already know how to program and debug when posting here.  Lots of stuff is explained on MSDN with many examples.